# ExtJS HTMLEditor toolbar gets disappeared after reaching specified height

Tags: extjs, html-editor

I am using ExtJS HTMLEditor and set the properties as follows-

```
{ xtype: "htmleditor", width: 500, height: 250}
```

While entering the text, after reaching the specified height, the toolbar gets disappeared.
I tried removing the height and setting `autoHeight: true`  but in both cases the HTML editor does not fit to the window (HTMLEditor is inside `Ext.form.FormPanel`).

Anyone having idea to solve it.

This is my code

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'This is Title',
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 500,
    layout: 'fit',
    closeAction: 'hide',
        items: [
                    new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                    border: false,
                    autoHeight: true,
                items: [
                    {  allowBlank: false, xtype:     
                                    "htmleditor", height: 250, width: 600, anchor:'100%'}
                ]
            })
         ],
         buttons: [
        {text: 'Ok' },
        {text: 'Cancel'}
         ]
     }).show();
});
```

Comment: a demo of your code in jsfiddle would be helful

Comment: I have added the code for the reference. In jsfiddle the issue is not reproducing correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem- Added `layout: 'fit'` to Formpanel

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'This is Title',
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 500,
    layout: 'fit',
    closeAction: 'hide',
        items: [
                    new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                    border: false,
                    layout: 'fit',   // This fixed the issue
                    items: [
                        {  allowBlank: false, 
                           xtype: "htmleditor", 
                           height: 250, 
                           width: 600
                        }
                    ]
            })
         ],
         buttons: [
                    {text: 'Ok' },
                    {text: 'Cancel'}
         ]
     }).show();
});
```